# Define multiple variable and Initial Value in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have to added multiple environment Variables and Initial Value in Environment Variables 
[image]

Using the same variables for API in Postman e.g. {{env}}/api/v1/searchvalue
Error Message display like below.
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to qa/api/v1/airport.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to reference them using `{{...}}` and not single `{...}` like you have in your environment file.

My variable values look like this:

[image: Env Values]

I am using the `{{url}}` variable for the request which resolves to `https://postman-echo.com/get?test=test`.

[image: URL]